# flutter filter array by a value

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to filter data by value of search

This is my data

```
{Items: [{ID: 1195, Name: Fajita Pizza (S)}, {ID: 1195, Name: Fajita Pizza (S)}, {ID: 1195, Name: Fajita Pizza (S)}]}
```

I have simple search fiald like this

```
            TextField (
                onChanged: (val) {
                  print(val);
               //here i need to just print a filter result 
                  
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: tr('search.search'),
                  alignLabelWithHint: true,
                  hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2,
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                ),
              ),
```

I just need to filter it onChanged just filter the product by name

I am trying something like this

```
        onChanged: (val) {
          print(val);
          print(items['Items'].where((food) => food.Name.toLowerCase().contains(val.toLowerCase()).toList()));
        },
```

but its not printing the list :(

Comment: Okay you mean to say if any user type any data to your textfield then it will search regarding to your data?

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede mean user type Pizza it will search in item name and print those item who have such name as pizza or faj so fajitta something like this

Comment: When user will type in textfield then you want to print right?

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede yes.  I think from  onChanged we can do

Comment: Not sure about this really. But let me check this also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so what you have to do is to run a Loop through the MAP data and filter them out, the approach would look like this

```dart
//from dartpad so ignore the void main() 
 void main() {
    List<String> _result = [];
    String searchString = "pizza"; //pass it from the onChanged Listner so itll be dynamic
    Map<String,List> _searchData = {"Items": [{"ID": 1195, "Name": "Fajita Pizza (S)"}, {"ID": 1195, "Name": "Fajita   Pizza (S)"}, {"ID": 1195, "Name": "Fajita Pizza (S)"}]};
  
   for(var i in _searchData["Items"]){
     if(i["Name"].toLowerCase().contains(searchString)){
        _result.add(i["Name"]);
     }
   }
   print(_result);
}
```

This will give you out suggestions that match that phrase and you can get the output from the _result List,

the output for this code will be

```dart
[Fajita Pizza (S), Fajita   Pizza (S), Fajita Pizza (S)]
```

and plugging into your code as per your idea it will look like

```dart
//On Global Scope for the Widgets
Map<String,List> _searchData = {"Items": [{"ID": 1195, "Name": "Fajita Pizza (S)"}, {"ID": 1195, "Name": "Fajita   Pizza (S)"}, {"ID": 1195, "Name": "Fajita Pizza (S)"}]};

... inside widget Tree

TextField (
           onChanged: (val) {
               print(val);
               String searchString = val; 
               for(var i in _searchData["Items"]){
                  if(i["Name"].toLowerCase().contains(searchString)){
                     print(i);
                  }
               }                  
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: tr('search.search'),
                  alignLabelWithHint: true,
                  hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2,
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                ),
              ),
```

This will filter out all the suggestions, and give you a list, and a small opinion, what i would suggest is that add a button to the widgets, so once the user clicks search, then you can just run this process only once, which improve the performance if you have a large set of data, but if the Data is small then we can go with this approach, and i have use

Map<String, List> for the data as you have specified it that way, kindly feel free to alter it, and if you use dart:convert, it will be more useful as we can handle them like objects.

Happy coding

As per the Comment, all you need to do is to directly take the value of "i" instead of taking the name of it,

```dart
{ID: 1195, Name: Fajita Pizza (S)}
{ID: 1195, Name: Fajita   Pizza (S)}
{ID: 1195, Name: Fajita Pizza (S)}
```

This will be your output.

Update as per comment
use this logic to add them as a map

```dart
Map<dynamic, dynamic>_result = {};
 for(var i in _sample["Items"]){
   if(i["Name"].toLowerCase().contains(searchString)){
      _result[i["ID"]] = i;
   }
 }  
print(_result);
```

The output

```dart
{Fajita Pizza (S): {ID: 1195, Name: Fajita Pizza (S)}, Fajita   Pizza (S): {ID: 1195, Name: Fajita   Pizza (S)}}
```

Thankyou

Comment: i dont need just name i need the all items which name match the search word

Comment: Hello i have updated the answer, as per your need, check the plugging it into your code section :)

Comment: I try its workin fine with name but when i add whole array mean _result.add(i) its not addming

Comment: It will not add because we are pushing in objects so, we have to have it as a Map, and not a list, so we have to declare a Map and push the values in them, with KEY:VALUE pair

Comment: but ID is also not adding can i add only Name ?

Comment: you can add any value you want, like instead of i["Name"] if you choose i["ID"] while adding it to the Map it will work, it is a Map, so you can add any value, and if your ID is a Double then you have to change the declaration of the Map to Map<Double, dynamic>_result = {};